# React/Redux How to set value from redux store to state of component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to change my received data from redux store to another variable (and then modify it).
At the moment, I receive data from store after API call and it is stored `offices`, but it is not set to my `officeData` variable. Does anyone how can I solve that?
This is my code:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const offices = useSelector((state) => state.office.offices)
  const [officeData, setOffices] = useState(offices);
  debugger;
  useEffect(()=> {
    dispatch(getOffices());
    setOffices(offices);
    debugger
  }, [dispatch])
```

Comment: Effect runs after the render so offices will probably be whatever you set the initial value of state.office.offfices to. When getOffices sets it then your component will render again so there is no need to copy offices from redux store to local state.

Comment: The thing is that later on I modify officeData variable and I need that component to be rendered every time with that data

Comment: And my component is not rerendered after data from dispatch is received.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't even enter your useEffect i think it's because you give `dispatch` as a dependency.

Effect are triggered when component mount but also when component update (prop or state). So you could do something like that :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const offices = useSelector((state) => state.office.offices);
const [officeData, setOffices] = useState(undefined);
const [didMount, setDidmount] = useState(false);

// When component mount, load your Offices data
useEffect(() => {
  if(!didMount){
    dispatch(getOffices());
    setOffices(offices);
  } else {
    setDidmount(true);
  }
});

useEffect(() => {
  if(didMount) {
    // When you update officeData, do your thing
  }
}, [officeData]);
```

I don't know the behavior of useSelector, but i guess it does not trigger a rendering. Maybe **you could have a useEffect with offices as dependency**, just be careful not to loop !